# Iterator returns size > 0 but won't output element

Tags: c++, memory, iterator

I have a set of type Tuple. Tuple contains a vector of strings. When I output the size for debugging it outputs a size of 4, which is correct, but then when I try to cout the first element I get crazy stuff(memory). Why does it not return the string?

```
    cout<<"temp size:"<<temp.getTuples().size()<<" r size:"<<r.getTuples().size()<<endl;
    set<Tuple>::iterator it=temp.getTuples().begin();
    t=*it;
    cout<<t.getTuple().size()<<" "<<t.getTuple()[0]<<endl;
    for(set<Tuple>::iterator it=temp.getTuples().begin();it!=temp.getTuples().end();++it)
    {
        for(set<Tuple>::iterator jt=r.getTuples().begin();jt!=r.getTuples().end();++jt)
        {
            t=*it;
            a=t.getTuple();
            e=*jt;
            b=e.getTuple();
            vector<string> ab;
            cout<<"a size:"<<t.getTuple().size()<<" b size:"<<e.getTuple().size()<<endl;
            cout<<"a size:"<<a.size()<<" b size:"<<b.size()<<endl;
```

[image: Code and output]

Sorry there are quite a lot of couts for debugging. Temp is the set of Tuples (of 3) printed out first in the console and r is the set of Tuples (of 5) printed out second. The 4 printed out is in reference to the size of a Tuple(the vector) in the set and is correct. The output should print '12345'. Any help on why its printing the memory location would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would guess that the `getTuples()` function returns a set by value. So your iterator `it` is made to point to an element of a temporary object here:

```
set<Tuple>::iterator it=temp.getTuples().begin();
```

De-referencing `it` is undefined behaviour. You must make sure you either make a copy of the thing returned by `getTuples()`, or modify it to return a reference.